# What's the difference between union and multi-union in jena ? What each is used for?

Tags: jena

as i am working with the shacl api, i have had to work with the multi-union. I have a sense of it. However i could not help but wonder what's the main difference between union and multi-union ?

Comment: Note: jena-shacl does not use MultiUnion. Other SHACL APIs may well do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MultiUnion` is a union of N graphs whereas `Union` is exactly 2 graph.

In addition, for `Union`, add and delete are applied to both as needed (e.g. add to left if not in right)

For `MultiUnion`, the base graph is updateably, the rest are not, and potential duplicates are handled in read operations like `find()`.

`MultiUnion` is the more common one to use.